# upload files into google drive folder from side bar UI

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make web app as a sidebar in spreadsheet using HTML5, Bootstrap 5 & JavaScript to make entry of data easier . I managed to go through the entire process But the problem that **I can't  make the button upload files into google drive folder and return with the url back.**

the link of sheet working with.

> I think the problem in this variable from html script but I don't know what is it

```
var url = document.getElementById("transaction-file").addEventListener('click',
            function(a){
              google.script.run.uploadFiles(this.parentNode)
            });
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D-tEPsUJqGbCHrF8CYQlPu_ZhmVIGDYEojHfO0_7rW4/edit?usp=sharing

**google script code**

```js
function loadForm() {
  
  const htmlForSidebar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("uform");
  const htmlOutput = htmlForSidebar.evaluate();
  htmlOutput.setTitle("Winter 2021");
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showSidebar(htmlOutput);
  
}


function createMenu(){
  
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu("My Forms");
  menu.addItem("Show UserForm", "loadForm");
  menu.addToUi();
  
}

function onOpen(){
  
  createMenu();

}

function uploadFiles(files){
  var file = files.myFile;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1gaNAb1s8j7wmotvRUJbg4yfJOFNdZYo5');
  var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
  return createFile.geturl();
}

function addNewRow(rowData) {

  const currentDate = new Date();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  ws.appendRow([currentDate, rowData.trxDate, rowData.account, rowData.trxID, rowData.amount, rowData.url, rowData.comment]);

  return true;
  
}


function getDropDownArray(){
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Ref");
  return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container pt-3">

    <h4 class="border-bottom pb-2 mb-4">Donations' Registration <span class="badge bg-secondary">Form</span></h4>
    <div id="userform">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="transaction-date" class="form-label">Transaction Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="transaction-date" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid date.</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="transaction-account" class="form-label">Account</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="transaction-account" required aria-label="select account" required>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid account.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="transaction-id" class="form-label">Transaction ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="transaction-id" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid ID.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="transaction-amount" class="form-label">Amount</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="transaction-amount" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid amount without any service fees.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="transaction-file" class="form-label">url</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="transaction-file" name="myFile" aria-label="file example" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please upload right file.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="transaction-memo" class="form-label">Memo</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="transaction-memo" rows="1"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="mainButton">Add to Database</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
    <script>

      function afterButtonClicked(){

        if(validate()){
          var trxDate = document.getElementById("transaction-date");
          var account = document.getElementById("transaction-account");
          var trxID = document.getElementById("transaction-id");
          var amount = document.getElementById("transaction-amount");
          var url = document.getElementById("transaction-file");
          var comment = document.getElementById("transaction-memo");
          var rowData = {trxDate: trxDate.value, account: account.value, trxID: trxID.value, amount: amount.value, url: url.value, comment: comment.value};
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData);
        } else {
          //handle this later
        }
      }

      function afterSubmit(e){

        clearFields(["transaction-date", "transaction-account", "transaction-id", "transaction-amount", "transaction-file", "transaction-memo"]);
      }

      function clearFields(fields){
        fields.forEach(function(field){
          var el = document.getElementById(field);
          el.value = "";     
        });
      }

      function validate(){

        var fieldsToValidate = document.querySelectorAll("#userform input, #userform select");
        //is-invalid

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(fieldsToValidate,function(el){
          if(el.checkValidity()){
            el.classList.remove("is-invalid");
          } else {
            el.classList.add("is-invalid");
          }
        });

        return Array.prototype.every.call(fieldsToValidate,function(el){
          return el.checkValidity();
        });
      }

      function afterSidebarLoads(){

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterDropDownArrayReturned).getDropDownArray();

      }
      function afterDropDownArrayReturned(arrayOfArrays){

        var account = document.getElementById("transaction-account");
        arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r){
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.textContent = r[0];
          account.appendChild(option);
        });

      }

      document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked);
      google.script.run.uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",afterSidebarLoads);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I'd try to add the event listener to a button not to a file.  You can't click the file. But I've never used bootstrap 5 which is probably why you haven't received any assistance as yet. I added bootstrap-5 tag but you might wish to check to make sure I got the correct one.  It might help.

Comment: thanks a lot,
I already call the eventListener after button clicked and tried to run the script `google.script.run.uploadFiles(this.parentNode)`
 but didn't get any result.
@Cooper

Comment: Currently your code attaches the click event to input of type file not button.

Comment: I didn't it, but it's now updated.
if you suggest where to add event listener, I can try and be thankful.

Comment: this.parentNode is often used in conjunction with a parent node of type form but in your case I see no form tag so I'm not sure what you mean.  The only parent node that can see is of type div so that just doesn't make sense to me.